# Showing that $|\delta(s,u)-\delta(s,v)|=1$ for every $(u,v)\in E$

Tags: graph-theory

Part of a problem in algorithms, I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> If $G=(V,E)$ is an undirected graph and $s\in V$ is the the root (has path from it to any other vertex in $G$)  so for every $(u,v)\in E$ we get $|\delta(s,u)-\delta(s,v)|=1$ where $\delta(s,u)$ is the shortest path between $s$ and $u$.

What I did: Split into two independent parts:

1. If in the shortest path between $s$ and $v$ does not contain $u$ this means that the shortest path between $s$ and $u$ is the shortest path between $s$ and $v$ and the edge $(u,v)$ so $\delta(s,u)=\delta(s,v)+1$.
2. If in the shortest path between $s$ and $v$ does contain $u$ this means...

Now I'm stuck. I want to say that if shortest path between $s$ and $v$ does contain $u$, then it should be the shortest path between $s$ and $v$ without the edge $(u,v)$. But why can I say it? Maybe the vertex $u$ does not come before the vertex $v$ in that path (something like $s\to u_1 \to \ldots \to u\to u_3\to \ldots \to v$). How to show it?

Comment: This... doesn't make any sense.  Consider the path graph of length $n$ (vertices $1,\ldots,n$, edges $\{1,2\}, \{2,3\},\ldots$). Then $\delta(1, 2)=1$ and $\delta(1, n)=n-1$.

Comment: @NickPeterson I meant $u,v\in V$ so there exists $(u,v)\in E$. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: It is still wrong. You want $|\delta(s,u) - \delta(s,v)| \le 1$: the difference can be $0$, for example if the graph is a triangle graph and $s, u, v$ are its three vertices.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.

Argue by contradiction.

Suppose there exists $u,v\in V$ such that $\{u,v\}\in E$ and $\lvert\delta(s,u)-\delta(s,v)\lvert>1$. Assume, without loss of generality, that $\delta(s,v)<\delta(s,u)$.

Let $P:=sw_1w_2\ldots w_kv$ be a shortest path from $s$ to $v$. Note that $u$ cannot be on this path. (Why?)

Then the path $P':=sw_1w_2\ldots w_kvu$ is a path of length $\delta(s,v)+1$ connecting $s$ to $u$... but $\delta(s,v)+1<\delta(s,u)$, which is shorter than $\delta(s,u)$, a contradiction.